# I want to display 1 record instead of displaying the whole Database, PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

```
dbconnect.php

<form method="post" action="a.php">
<select name="taskOption" id="cust-id" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<?php
include 'orderSelect.php';
echo '<option>View Order</option>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;?>
<option value='<?php echo $row[0]; ?>'><?php echo $row[1]; echo " "; 
 echo $row[2]; ?></option>
 <?php endwhile; ?>

</select>
</form>
```

a.php

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$q = intval($_GET['q']);


$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname,productOne, quantity, price 
FROM   orderlist";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo "<table >
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Product</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr>";


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$tquan = $row['quantity'];
$tprice = $row['price'];
$total = $tquan * $tprice;

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['productOne'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $total . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

I got it working. IT display the record/ users that I want to see when something is selected from the drop down list, but the problem is it's displaying the entire database data. I only want to get that specific that of the selected person. Any Ideas how to solve this problem? I would appreciate it.

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjXze.png)

I only wanted the first row to be selected when I select from the dropdown list

Comment: at the end of your query, either add a `where` clause, or `limit 1`. I would think, in fact, you would want `where id = $q` wouldn't you?

Comment: can you give an example. i I didn't get you. I'm fairly new with this. Cheers.

Comment: i.e. `$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname,productOne, quantity, price 
FROM   orderlist where id = $q";`  You should look into using parameterization since this might be open to sql injection, but I think this is the basic idea you're looking for.

Comment: where is the variable `$q` derived from? The form appears to have one element, notably the select element, which is named `taskOption`

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SELECT is of the whole database you need to select something exact.

For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT 'id' FROM Users WHERE username='$name'";
```

That is an example of using the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the above said.
You mentioned you only wanted 1 record.

Add " LIMIT 1" to the end of your query

OR

Change the 'while' command to an 'if' command and it will only run once.

Comment: the database server would still send all the records, you'd just only read one of them in the php if you just change while to if. It could become a performance problem.

Comment: OP looks to be using the old mysql functions, and fetch will only bring out one row. I don't see any performance issues with it